# Why do the signals for second harmonic generation and third harmonic generation differ in the strong focusing limit (strongly focused gaussian beam)?

Tags: optics, signal-processing, non-linear-optics

In Ward & New (1969), the expression for second harmonic generation (SHG) and third harmonic generation (THG) intensity is derived for the focal volume of a strongly focused gaussian beam (axially thick medium).

The predicted value of the J-integral term in the expression for intensity of SHG under perfect phase matching conditions ($\Delta k=0$) is found to be π on page 184.

While for THG, the value of the J-integral term in the expression for intensity under perfect phase matching conditions ($\Delta k=0$) is found to be zero.

For THG, things seem to make sense. Third harmonic light generated before focus is born with a phase that is π radians out of phase with third harmonic light that is born after focus.

Since there is no phase slippage ($\Delta k$) of the funamental pump wave before and after focus except for that caused by the Gouy phase shift, the third harmonic light destructively interferes since it's π radians out of phase.

I don't understand why if this logic works with THG, it doesn't work for SHG.  What am I missing?

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to [Physics.SE]!  I've edited your post to explain the acronyms and include MathJaX coding.  One question, though:  is the intensity really π for SHG under perfect matching, or is it something else?  (I'm not well-versed enough in non-linear optics to know, but it seems weird that this is a value without units.)  If that's actually a typo, please [edit] your question appropriately to correct it.

Comment: Thats because propagation is $\omega t - k r$ and then odd harmonics will have odd multiples of $\pi$ as a phase shift due to the gouy phase while even harmonics do not. Also consider looking into Boyd where he further shows for a negative phase mismatch (or was it positive?, whichever the refractive index of $3\omega$ is lower than for $\omega$) you again have a signal. Only in the case for positive up to 0 $\Delta k$ do you have perfect cancellation.